# van der Waerden's proof that a monic $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has Galois group $S_n$ with probability 1

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sieve-theory

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2853.pdf) mentions that van der Waerden proved some results on the density of monic integer polynomials with Galois group the symmetric group $S_n$ in 1936. I have found [van der Waerden's original paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01707594) in German. Can anyone supply a link to, or restate/sketch, his argument in English? Thanks.